# Using Django/html forms can I pass multiple user inputs/values into a list to return/filter a database

Tags: django-forms, django-filter

I would like to filter or return certain data sets with the same "lookup_ref" but I would like to be able to look up multiple "lookup_ref" at one time.

I have searched and I can't find a way of doing this... my thoughts are:

1. with form checkboxes to see which data sets the user would like to return
2. use that input to create a list
3. only return data base entries which have the "lookup_ref" in that list.

have I gone down the wrong route? is there a better way of doing this?

```
models.pys

class qtable(models.Model):
    lookup_ref_choices = (
    ('gen', 'gen'),
    ('stolen_car', 'stolen_car'),
    ('assault', 'assault'),
)

lookup_ref = models.CharField(choices = lookup_ref_choices, max_length=20)
quest = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
order = models.FloatField(default = None)

views.py 
def get_user_input(request):
    form = Input_Form
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'input.html',context )

forms.py
class Input_Form(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = qtable
    fields = "__all__"
    exclude = ['quest', 'order']
    qtable = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        queryset = qtable.objects.all()
    )
```

Comment: Consider improving this question with code samples of what you've tried!

Comment: I have added the code - thanks